# Add extra formatting to td element in table (<b> or <i>)

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a text value in  element of the table. I need to add extra bold or italic styling to those elements.

The clean code is:

```
<td class="ar-table-col" rowspan="1">"Food Consumption Score: Acceptable Food Consumption Score"</td>
```

text after double dots has to be italic

Tried this:

```
<td class="ar-table-col" rowspan="1"><p><b>Food</b> Consumption Score: <i>Percentage of households with Acceptable Food Consumption Score</i></p></td>
```

did not help.

Any bright ideas on this case? (I don't exclude that rowspan is the reason of this, but it is required for this table)

Comment: Try to put >>> style="font-style: italic !important" <<< in the <i>-Tag. Its possible that the ar-table-col Class ignores your simple <i>-Tag.

Comment: See how to create a [minimal, concrete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As far as the code you've shared, the styling should work as expected. There is probably some kind of CSS overriding the native styling of your `<b>` and `<i>` tags.

Comment: You are welcome, Igor! More elegant would be to put a separate Class into your Stylesheet, containing that.

Comment: @Bernhard it is tricky as data is processed on backend by pandas and than integrated as simple json the only way to add partial styling to text in my case is reading specific "flags" to get places that have to be extra styled

Comment: why don't you use use`<strong>` and `<em>` tags ?

Comment: @MisterJojo your suggest is even better. Was not using as was not sure if pdf generator, which uses the same json which is used by front-end ui, will recognize them - checked - works fine